# Parse Group Messaging App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, chat, livechat

First off, I know that this question doesn't really fit the Q&A format of this site, but I can't think of where else to put this. I am trying to make an app with a group messaging portion. By googling around I see that parse seems to be the best option. I have seen [this](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parsecom) tutorial, but it seems out of date (the parse interface has changed a lot and the `PF_EGOTableHeader` seems nowhere to be found. I am wondering how to get set up. I have my app to be `push` and am wondering if this is best and if there are any updated tutorials or guides for this stuff.

Examples:
This is the parse in the tutorial
[image: Old Parse]

And this is the new parse:

[image: New parse]

They are quite different, and I don't know where to start. (I'm programming in Objective-C and would not like any Swift tutorials.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse is not really design for a Realtime app like messaging...I don't know if u really need it real-time or u'r fine if it slow push notification. If u want to make Real-time messaging app, i suggest [PunNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) instead, it also have free plan

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on the site, so I'll try my best.

Parse is a 3rd party database. So if you want to implement a group chat feature, you'll need to connect your app to parse ([check out this](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/new)). To make use of parse to implement chat functionality, since it's not realtime, you'll need to create a new class that stores all the messages sent and which group their sent to.

Then in the app, you'll need to make a timer that refreshes ever x amount of seconds, that will retrieve all the messages sent to that group.

Good luck.

Comment: How exactly would I retrieve?

Comment: Check out https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects but how tj3n said, a better idea would be to use a real time connection. If you want to develop something yourself, you could use websockets (socket.io is great). If not, check out firebase or PunNub.